# How to open evince in the top-right corner of my screen?

Tags: window-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a keyboard shortcut to move windows to a specific screen edge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56004/create-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-windows-to-a-specific-screen-edge)

I want to open a new evince window on the top-right corner of my screen, how can I do that in Ubuntu 11.04 with no Unity, but the old window manager system?

Comment: Please check if you can do something similar to this to evince. http://superuser.com/questions/72176/linux-set-default-terminal-size-and-screen-position

Comment: The answer to your question can be found at this question - [Create a keyboard shortcut to move windows to a specific screen edge](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56004/create-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-windows-to-a-specific-screen-edge)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with compiz.

- Install **CompizConfig Settings Manager** from the software center.
- In **Window Management** go to **Place Windows**.
- Go to the **Fixed Window Placement** tab; in **Windows with fixed placement** click on **New**.
- In **positioned window** type `class=Evince`. Set the position relative to the top-left of your screen.

In **System** -> **Preferences** -> **Appearance** enable visual effects.

Comment: I've been looking for something like this for quite some time, because evince was popping up on the other monitor-TV, not on the default monitor. And randomly, not with all PDFs. I hope this fixes the issue. I'll try it ASAP. Thank you!