# Create a keyboard shortcut to move windows to a specific screen edge

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, window-management

CompizConfig Settings Manager in Ubunte versions < 11.04 have the ability to create keyboard shortcuts that will send the currently active window to a specific screen location. e.g. I had my computer set up so that <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> sent the current window to the top-right corner of the current virtual desktop.

So far I have managed to get everything set up the way that I like in Natty without dealing with the chaos den that is the CCSM. In trying to fix this I have seen at least one guide that suggested that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Num 0</kbd> to <kbd>Num 9</kbd> will do what I want, which suggests that it is possible in a default install, but I'm on a laptop and have no numpad.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the **Grid Plugin** in CCSM - you can change the different shortcuts which are usually on the keypad!

Comment: So this is what I was trying to avoid, but at the same time 12 hours is Way too long to spend trying to fix your window manager just because you're feeling obstinate. And this is the thing that actually works.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your  <kbd>Super</kbd> is a shortcut to show the launcher and thus is preventing you to bind it to others functions.
See: [Can I define keyboard shortcuts using the Super key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34145/can-i-define-keyboard-shortcuts-using-the-super-key/34280)

Then you can go to ccsm and configure as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that the *actual* compiz plugin that I wanted is "put", not "grid". Grid will resize windows, put just moves 'em.